# Memory's increasing in react native app example, using Instruments

Tags: xcode, react-native, instruments

I've started to learn React-Native. I just created the basic React-Native project using ***react-native init AwesomeProject*** command then I had a look in Instruments in order to check the memory usage. I discovered that the memory is increasing continuously. Look at the picture. What do you think about it? Is that OK?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a memory leak in React Native for iOS version 0.15 and 0.16 when development mode is enabled. Either disable development mode or use the 0.17 release candidate.